# React useState reruns the component function on no change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

in this very simple demo

```
import { useState } from 'react';
 
function App() {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  console.log('App component Init');
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Let's get started! </h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCheck(true);
        }}
      >
        ClickMe
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

i get one log on app init,

upon the first click (state changes from false to true) i get another log as expected.

But on the second click  i also get a log , although the state remains the same.(interstingly the ReactDevTools doesn't produce the highlight effect around the component as when it is rerendered)

For every following clicks no log is displayed.

Why is this extra log happening.
Here is a stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wvaymj?file=index.tsx
Thanks in advance

Comment: check state is true and i think it always is true. so view not render. you can try    
       setCheck(!check);

Comment: to stop these extra rendering use "useCallback". useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed, so it stop extra rendering if same value pass to a function

Comment: @Sanoodia `useCallback` would be completely useless here, as there are no dependent components which would receive that callback as a prop.

Comment: I included a stackblitz demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wvaymj?file=index.tsx
Press the button and see the logs
I'm just trying to see how useState works not to create something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

> i get one log on app init,
>
> upon the first click (state changes from false to true) i get another
> log as expected.
>
> But on the second click i also get a log , although the state remains
> the same.(interstingly the ReactDevTools doesn't produce the highlight
> effect around the component as when it is rerendered)
>
> For every following clicks no log is displayed.

And your question being

> Why is this extra log happening?

Check the `useState` [Bailing Out of a State Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) section (*emphasis mine*):

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)
>
> ***Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out.*** That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with `useMemo`.

The answer to your question is essentially, "It's just the way React and the `useState` hook work." I'm guessing the second additional render is to check that no children components need to be updated, and once confirmed, all further state updates of the same value are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you console log check you can see...

The first click you will get `check` is `true` -> check state change from false (init) => true (click) => state change => view change => log expected.

The second click => check state is true (from frist click) => true => state not change => view not render.

So. you can try

```
 setCheck(!check);
```

Comment: I included a stackblitz demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wvaymj?file=index.tsx
Press the button and see the logs I'm just trying to see how useState works not to create something.

Comment: useState work but Nothing changes.

Comment: Use prevState callback when mutating state based on a previous state. So instead of going setCheck(!check), instead go with setCheck((prevState) => !prevState). This will ensure you get the "latest previous" state.